Reference for Density question
Let $ B $ be a reflexive, separable Banach space and $ p \in (1,\infty)$. Then denote by $L^{p}(B)$ the space of all functions $$ f : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to B $$ with
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \vert f \vert^{p}_{B} < \infty
$$
Now define $L^{p} \times B$ to be the space of all functions $ F : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to B $ such that $F$ is a finite linear combinations of functions of the form
$$ 
f(x) b
$$
Where $ f \in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $ b \in B $. Then I want a reference that gives a proof to the fact that $L^{p} \times B $ is dense in $L^{p}(B)$. I found the statement written on some book on Harmonic analysis but without a proof and I can't find a reference.

The space of linear combinations of functions $x\mapsto f(x)b$ is the tensor product $L^p(\mathbb R^n)\otimes B$. Did you check the book Vector Measures of Diestel and Uhl?

An explicit reference is Lemma 1.2.19 in T. Hytönen, J. van Neerven, M. Veraar, L. Weis, Analysis in Banach Spaces, Vol. 1 (Springer 2016). Neither reflexivity nor separability matter here.

@DirkWerner Thank you for the reference.
